# System.IO.File.Exists not working after publishing the website

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, file-permissions

System.IO.File.Exists not working after publishing the website.I need to check whether an exe file already exist in a path using 'System.IO.File.Exists'.It worked fine in localhost ,but not working after publishing the site.I think its due to permission any alternative exists?please help.

My code like:

```
foreach (var item in reslt)
        {
            if (System.IO.File.Exists(item.Path))
            {
                flag = true;
                using (APM context = new APM())
                {
                    var res = (
                        from s in context.T_SoftwarePath
                        where s.UserID == user
                        select s).ToList();
                    res.ForEach(s => s.Value = twoinone);
                    context.SaveChanges();
                }

                Process.Start(item.Path);
                break;
            }
        }

        if (flag == false)
        {
            f1 = Download(twoinone);
        }
```

Comment: did you include your file in your project so that it gets published?

Comment: What kind of error is shown?

Comment: _"not working after publishing the website"_ Probably the webserver can't access the path or it even doesn't exist locally on that server. What's the content of `item.Path`?

Comment: @khlr path looks like C:\Program Files\TellerSoft Pvt Ltd\Tellersoft\Tellersoft.exe

Comment: So I guess this path exists locally on your dev machine while it doesn't exist on the server, does it?

Comment: @khlr yes    correct

Comment: Unless you provide more information on your dev machine, the target machine and the specific path, there will be no answer.